# Array of strings (char array) in C (Arduino). How do I accomplish it?

Tags: c, arrays, arduino, chars

I want to access certain data which basically looks like this:

```
char* a[]={
    "0000000000",
    "0000000000",
    "0011111100",
    "0000100100",
    "0000100100",
    "0011111100",
    "0000000000",
    "0000000000",
};
```

I have around 200 of those data sets and want to access it in the way.

`fooBar[23];` --> This should return the 23rd character array (which looks like the example listed above).

As far as I understand from my other programming knowledge, I would need an array of Strings. The array index is my lookup number (which will be a maximum of 255). The array values are the character arrays as shown above.

How can this be accomplished with C (Arduino IDE)?

Comment: You've already shown the solution to your question. So what is unclear about that?

Comment: Note that `fooBar[23]` is actually the 24th character array. I know nothing about arduino and what restrictions it places on the use of C but the proposed array is correct (maybe change type to `const char*` as string literals should not be modified).

Comment: to make it more clear: i need an array of the example array construct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a two dimensional array. Like:

```
char a[][]={
    "0000000000",
    "0000000000",
    "0011111100",
    "0000100100",
    "0000100100",
    "0011111100",
    "0000000000",
    "0000000000",
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comment, I *think* this is what you are asking for:

```
const char* data_sets[][200] =
    {
        { "00000", "11111",         },
        { "22222", "33333", "44444" },
        { "55555"                   },
    };
```

Each entry in `data_sets` is an array of 200 `const char*`. For accessing:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(data_sets) / sizeof(data_sets[0]); i++)
{
    const char** data_set = data_sets[i];
    printf("data_set[%u]\n", i);
    for (size_t j = 0; data_set[j]; j++)
    {
        printf("  [%s]\n", data_set[j]);
    }
}
```

See online demo at http://ideone.com/6kq2M.